# What should I use Ubuntu for?

Tags: multimedia

I need some of your precious advice co-Ubuntu users.

I have been a full Ubuntu user for a few months now and our old 2005 model PC just broke down and so my parents gave me a new PC (notebook). I have installed Windows 7 Ultimate for some reason.

Now, my problem is that, since I am a amateur graphic designer, website developer, software developer and other professions a normal teenager won't try and I am using Adobe Creative Suite CS6 Master Collection for my multimedia creation and web development needs, what could I use Ubuntu Linux for? Software development? Website Usability Testing? Other Multimedia stuff? Etc.?

Need real help because my mind is getting confused in what should I use Ubuntu for...
Any help will be welcomed with appreciation. :D

P.S. Don't suggest to me any games because I'm no gamer.

Comment: "a normal teenager won't try" - epic :D

Comment: The QA format is really a good fit for "problem" -> "answer".  It doesn't really work with discussion or list questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my perspective, you should use Ubuntu to wider your knowledge.

I am PhD student at the moment but was advise to use ubuntu during my undergrad study by one of the prof. There was a platform to simulate robot, one of this mystic platforms for real geeks. The platform worked very well on linux and nearly not at all on windows.

I switched to ubuntu and started to 'fight' with it, but.. I found that you can do a lot of stuff and have a lot of access to knowledge if you in Linux/openSource. After years of asking myself, why I am doing all this difficult way, I can say that this way can have you mastering of your computer's interaction.

So to make the answer:
You should use ubuntu because one day you will know or can do something, what your colleagues form window's world will have no idea about. And this will give you huge advantage.

Apart of this you can use ubuntu for everything the same you using windows

Answer (score 1):

Well You should use Ubuntu to get a deeper knowledge of the underlying system which providing the environment for you to use various softwares and programs.

But, here is my suggestions: If you must professionally use Adobe tools for graphics design, I would not recommend Ubuntu for this. Because despite it's awesomeness gimp still isn't as good as Adobe tools. Also some working environments strictly require the work from an Adobe tool.

But, if you are a programmer, not matter what type of program it is, such as developing web applications, softwares for PCs, Ubuntu is the perfect choice for you. Historically Linux has very solid background on this side.

Here is my recommendation, Use Ubuntu as a dual boot system.  When you have to work for graphics, use the Windows system. When doing developing softs, switch to Ubuntu. Also use it for other activities as this will greatly enrich your knowledge about the operation of Operating systems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but like what activities?

Comment: Normal usage, such as browsing Internet, doing home work etc

Answer (score 0):

1. install ubuntu from wubi alongside windows 7
2. use ubuntu for Security and virus-free environment, Multimedia, desktop, free, more than 40,000 free app in software center ...

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bit of an off-topic question here (see the FAQ), but here I try.

For website development, Ubuntu might be great -- when it comes to the technicalities behind the scenes. Web servers, scripting languages. CGIs, databases, code editors -- Ubuntu is a developers dream come true, everything is comparatively easy to install and manage. Learning a computer language is *much* easier if installing the environment is simple, and if it is open source (so you can look inside of the mechanics to see how things actually work) and well documented.

When it comes to graphic design -- it sucks. Yes, you have nice amateurish tools like gimp for photo editing and inkscape for vector graphics, but that is not the same level with what the professionals use. Certainly not on par with the top shelf Adobe products (monitor color calibration profiles anyone?).